# How is my filename referenced before assignment?

Tags: python, flask

Whenever i try to run my code i get 'local variable 'filename' referenced before assignment'.
however in my app.route i define filename before i use it. How do I fix it?

here is the code that isnt working:

```
@app.route('/getfileHelper', methods=['GET','POST'])
def getfileHelper():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['imgfile']
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)   #from werkzeug import secure_filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash("No file selected. Please select an image file")
            return render_template('selectImage.html')
        texts = detect_text('static/images/'+filename)

        text_translations = [] #emty list for dictionary of original text and translation
        for text in texts:
            translate_client = translate.Client()  # Instantiates a client
            translate_text = text.description  # The text to translate
            source = 'en'  # The source language
            target = request.args["lang_target"]  # The target language 
            translation = translate_client.translate(translate_text, source_language=source, target_language=target)
            text_translations.append({'text':translate_text, 'translation':translation['translatedText']})

            db_append(filename, translate_text, translation['translatedText'])
    return render_template('home.html', filename=filename, text_translations=text_translations)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return render_template('home.html', filename=filename, text_translations=text_translations)
```

Suppose that the input `request.method == 'GET'`. What do you expect the value of `filename` to be, and why? Where will that value come from? Solve that, and you solve the problem (except that the same problem also applies to `text_translations`). I can't be more specific, because I don't know what you actually want the code to do in this case.